# Reference return value and value updation in destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int i; //1 - global

class Test
{
public:
    ~Test()
    {
        i = 10;
    }
};

int& foo()
{
    int i = 3; //2 - local
    Test ob;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "i = " << foo() << endl; // output: i = 3
    return 0;
}
```

I have queries for above code:

1. Variable i being local to foo, reference of which cannot be used (automatic variable). How does above code execute?
2. The Test object in foo function will be destroyed after return statement. How does foo function returns reference of 2 (i = 3)?

Comment: `i = 3;` (and `i = 10;`) does not declare a new variable, it still uses the global one

Comment: @UnholySheep Updated the question, please look into it now.

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land, where invalid code don't necessarily crashes.

Comment: After the edit your code invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: @UnholySheep.. tried here http://cpp.sh/6uhbc (output i =3, each run)

Comment: And on IDEOne it causes a runtime error: https://ideone.com/5hKuFd - just because one compiler creates code that "works" does not mean your code is correct

Comment: Also if I change the optimization level in the link you provided the result changes as well (your tests weren't very thorough)

Comment: Yes true @UnholySheep

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot How is it allowed in C++ standards?

Comment: @VishvajeetT the standard simply says that reading or writing into a dead object is undefined behavior. It's up to the implementation to decide how to behave. In that case, there is no runtime check done to see if the variable is dead. If it happen to work, it does. If it happen to crash, so be it. I recommend you to use a "undefined behavior sanitizer", which will add those runtime checks for you to debug your code.

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumeRacicot

Answer (score 4):

> Variable `i` being local to `foo`, reference of which cannot be used (automatic variable). How does above code execute?

What you are doing is cause for undefined behavior. Unfortunately, seemingly sane behavior falls under undefined behavior too. [A legendary answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/434551) expounds on the subject.

> The `Test` object in `foo` function will be destroyed after return statement. How does `foo` function returns reference of 2 (i = 3)?

The first statement is correct. However, that is not relevant to the issue of which `i` is returned from `foo`. `foo` returns a reference to the function local variable regardless of what `Test` does.

Comment: Helpful link !!

Comment: @VishvajeetT, when I read that answer the first time, I was awe struck. What a great analogy to explain undefined behavior!

Answer (score 2):

You always read and wrote the global `i` since you never declared local `i` or class member `i` in your code.

Comment: This _was_ a correct answer to the posted question.  Now the question has been edited to ask what I believe is a follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

when you call `foo()` like

```
cout << "i = " << foo() << endl;
```

This block of code will execute

```
int& foo() {
    i = 3; //2 - local
    Test ob; /* object having local scope */
    return i;
}/* when it goes out of this block.. destructor gets called */
```

above you are creating object `ob`. when it came out of scope, destructor `~Test() { }` gets called automatically & in `destructor` you have `i=10`, so `return i;` will return `i` value which was there in destructor. so it prints `i` value as `10`. Also `i = 3;` doesn't create new `i` it will consider global declared `i`.

**updated code :**

```
int& foo() {
    int i = 3; /* here i is locally created */
    Test ob;
    return i; /* you can't return reference to local variable.. invokes UB */
}
```

Above code block will cause undefined behavior.